# How do I select from another table by an id within a select statement?

Tags: sql

I have three tables, one for post_replies, one for reply_likes (a record of "likes"), and another for reply_dislikes.

The reply_likes's reply_id column corresponds to the id column in the post_replies table.

Essentially, I am trying to perform sort of like a foreach operation, where for each  post reply, retrieve the count of likes from the reply_likes table.

This is the same sort of situation for the reply_dislikes table too.

post_replies table:

```
 +-------+-----------+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
 |  id   |  post_id  |  owner_id  | reply_content | created_at  |  is_shown     |
 +-------+-----------+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
 | int   |   int     |    int     |   text        |  timestamp  |    bool       |
 +-------+-----------+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
```

reply_likes table:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
|  id   | user_id | reply_id  |
+-------+---------+-----------+
|  int  |  int    |  int      |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

I tried the following and it did not work:

```
 SELECT fc.id AS replyId, user.username AS owner, fc.reply_content AS content, 
 fc.created_at AS createdAt, COUNT(rl.id) AS likes
 FROM forum_replies fc 
 JOIN users user
 ON fc.owner_id = user.id 
 JOIN reply_likes rl 
 ON fc.id = rl.reply_id
 WHERE fc.post_id = :postId AND fc.is_shown = 1
 ORDER BY fc.created_at DESC
```

The problem with this approach is that the fc.id has not been retrieved yet to be used to select from the other table

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

you should group table when you are trying to select functions like count. Answer will look like:

```
SELECT fc.id AS replyId, user.username AS owner, fc.reply_content AS content, 
 fc.created_at AS createdAt, COUNT(rl.id) AS likes
 FROM forum_replies fc 
 JOIN users user
 ON fc.owner_id = user.id 
 JOIN reply_likes rl 
 ON fc.id = rl.reply_id
 WHERE fc.post_id = (I do not know what does it mean):postId AND fc.is_shown = 1
 GROUP BY fc.id, user.username, fc.reply_content, fc.created_at
 ORDER BY fc.created_at DESC
```

Only what I did not understand what does mean "fc.post_id = :postId". Other way, after add "Group by" un your code script will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `group by` to make your `count()` work:

```
SELECT fc.id AS replyId, user.username AS owner, fc.reply_content AS content, 
 fc.created_at AS createdAt, COUNT(rl.id) AS likes
 FROM forum_replies fc 
 JOIN users user
 ON fc.owner_id = user.id 
 JOIN reply_likes rl 
 ON fc.id = rl.reply_id
 WHERE fc.post_id = :postId AND fc.is_shown = 1
 Group by fc.id, u.username, fc.reply_content, fc.created_at
 ORDER BY fc.created_at DESC
```